# cannot assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'NSData?' in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am using `CoreData` for an app. I have set image as `BinaryData` in data model. But I have fetched image from server as `UIImage` and it throws error as:

```
cannot assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'NSData?
```

I searched but couldn't find any resemblance solution for it. Can anyone help me in swift 3?
My code is:

```
let url1:URL = URL(string:self.appDictionary.value(forKey: "image") as! String)!
let picture = "http://54.243.11.100/storage/images/news/f/"
let strInterval = String(format:"%@%@",picture as CVarArg,url1 as CVarArg) as String as String
let url = URL(string: strInterval as String)
SDWebImageManager.shared().downloadImage(with: url, options: [],progress: nil, completed: {[weak self] (image, error, cached, finished, url) in
   if self != nil {
      task.imagenews = image //Error:cannot assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'NSData?'
   }
})
```

Comment: What is the type of the variable task.imagenews ?

Comment: To help you we need more. What is task.imagenews? What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear - you cannot assign `UIImage` object to a variable of `NSData` type.

To convert `UIImage` to Swift's `Data` type, use `UIImagePNGRepresentation`

```
var data : Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

Note that if you're using Swift, you should be using Swift's type `Data` instead of `NSData`

Comment: Your answer is nice one.. I made it very complex

Answer (score 0):

You must convert, image into `Data` (or `NSData`) to support `imagenews` data type.

Try this

```
let url1:URL = URL(string:self.appDictionary.value(forKey: "image") as! String)!
let picture = "http://54.243.11.100/storage/images/news/f/"
let strInterval = String(format:"%@%@",picture as CVarArg,url1 as CVarArg) as String as String
let url = URL(string: strInterval as String)
SDWebImageManager.shared().downloadImage(with: url, options: [],progress: nil, completed: {[weak self] (image, error, cached, finished, url) in
   if self != nil {

     if let data = img.pngRepresentationData {  // If image type is PNG
           task.imagenews = data     
      } else if let data = img.jpegRepresentationData { // If image type is JPG/JPEG
          task.imagenews = data     
     } 


   }
})



// UIImage extension, helps to convert Image into data
extension UIImage {

        var pngRepresentationData: Data? {
            return UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
        }

        var jpegRepresentationData: Data? {
            return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0)
        }
    }
```